# How can I display an expression in unevaluated form?

Tags: output-formatting, traditional-form

How can I display an expression in unevaluated form?

```
TraditionalForm[2*3^3 + 5^2]
```

I´d like to obtain 2*3^3 + 5^2 displayed in traditional form without being evaluated to obtain 79.

---

Added after bobthechemist's answer

How could I obtain the behavior I want from a String (The expression is stored in a string)?

```
a = "2*3^3+5^2"
Defer[a]
Defer[ToExpression[a]]
```

Comment: `Defer` is what you are looking for, I think.

Comment: @bobthechemist Yes!. Thank you. You can answer and I set as the solution.

Comment: @bobthechemist and how to obtain that from a expression as a String?. a = "2*3^3+5^2"
Defer[a]
Defer[ToExpression[a]]

Comment: I don't think that will be possible, since the superscripts are not a standard font.  I'm not well versed with the underlying mechanisms for formatting in Mathematica, but that output has a bunch of `Boxes` that probably can't be turned into strings easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `TraditionalForm` in this case; rather, use `Defer`.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for [`ToExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) says

[image: quote]

So

```
a = "2*3^3+5^2";
ToExpression[a, TraditionalForm, Defer]
```

gives

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

`HoldForm` is beter.

```
a = 2*3^3 + 5^2 // HoldForm
a // TraditionalForm
8 a // TraditionalForm
8 a // ReleaseHold
```